# Foreach loop in Reviews.io API

Tags: php, json, api

I'm very new to the world of APIs and am currently trying to display all reviews I have on my reviews.io account. I've tried to make the following script, which now seems to work, however, I would love to have the results sorted nicely in a for-each loop.

Here my current script:

```
    <?php
    //  Initiate curl
        $header_data = array(
            'store' => 'myID',
            'apikey' => 'myAPIKEY',
            'method'  => 'GET'
             );

        $ch = curl_init();
        $curlOpts = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.reviews.co.uk/merchant/reviews?store=myID',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header_data,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false
        );  
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));   
        $review = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($review);
        echo '</pre>';


    ?>
```

This outputs all reviews in Raw code or JSON I believe, however, I would like to have them displayed nicely in a div for each item.

The output is as follows (formatted):

```
    {
      "stats": {
        "total_reviews": 45,
        "average_rating": "4.93"
      },
      "store": "Mystore",
      "word": "Excellent",
      "per_page": 10,
      "page": 0,
      "total_pages": 5,
      "reviews": [
        {
          "store_review_id": 7418538,
          "title": "",
          "comments": "I had a wonderful experience ...",
          "date_created": "2020-01-21 03:52:19",
          "rating": 5,
          "user_id": 9107944,
          "store_branch_id": 0,
          "timeago": "22 hours ago",
          "date_formatted": "21st January 2020",
          "reviewer": {
            "first_name": "Edward",
            "last_name": "",
            "verified_buyer": "yes",
            "address": ""
          },
          "ratings": [],
          "branch": null,
          "images": [],
          "replies": []
        },
        {
          "store_review_id": 7418539,
          "title": "",
          "comments": "Imagine an experience In a far away land where all you do is enjoy the sights ...",
          "date_created": "2020-01-21 03:52:45",
          "rating": 5,
          "user_id": 9107947,
          "store_branch_id": 0,
          "timeago": "22 hours ago",
          "date_formatted": "21st January 2020",
          "reviewer": {
            "first_name": "Marcos",
            "last_name": "",
            "verified_buyer": "yes",
            "address": ""
          },
          "ratings": [
            {
              "id": 1176695,
              "store_review_id": 7418539,
              "score": "yes",
              "name": "Was your tour good value?"
            }
          ],
          "branch": null,
          "images": [],
          "replies": []
        }
      ],
      "whitelisted_urls": []
    }
```

Now, I am able to display single values such as using:

```
    <?php

    echo '<p>';
    echo $data['stats']['total_reviews']; 
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo $data['stats']['average_rating']; 
    echo '</p>';

    ?>

    <?php
    echo '<p>';
    echo $data['reviews'][0]['comments']; 
    echo '</p>';

    ?>
```

however, what I would really like to achieve now is to display a div class for each of the reviews, containing e.g. the first_name and the comments.

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated as I am very new to APIs. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop the `$data['reviews']`.

```
foreach($data['reviews'] as $val){
    echo '<div>';
    echo 'Name: ' . $val['reviewer']['first_name'] . '<br/>'; 
    echo 'Comment: ' . $val['comments']; 
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works well indeed. Appreciate your help!